# FindString() method for wx ListBox not working for me

Tags: wxpython

This is a part of the code which successfully displays the values in the dict art in a wxListBox.
However, nothing I try returns other than -1 from the last line below. Can anyone see why it doesn't work?

```
    art = {'A1':'Horace Silver', 'A2':'Murray Perahia', 'A3':'Kieth Jarret',
           'A4':'Andras Schiff', 'A5':'Tord Gustavsen Trio'}
    art = dict(sorted(art.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
    self.list_box_1.InsertItems(list(art.values()),0)
    print(self.list_box_1.FindString('ray', True))
```

I have tried with and without case sensitivity, single and double quotes around the string, whole words and parts. No error messages are sent.

I gave up looking for the error and discovered that this function works:-

```
def checkname(self,l,n):
    for i in range(l.GetCount()):
        name = l.GetString(i)
        x = name.find(n,0)
        if x > -1:
            return [i, name]
```

l is the name of a listbox and n is the string to find. It is limited to looking from the beginning.

Comment: I also tried omitting the dict sorting.

Comment: Could you provide an MWE (Minimum Workable/Reproducible Example) for this issue? It seems that this snippet is part of a larger class.

Comment: Sadly I cannot get past the stackoverflow error check - it asks me to reformat the indents whwen try to paste the whole program in.

Comment: Yes, but the point of the MWE is to make the code as short as (reasonably) possible while still showcasing the issue.

Comment: Other than the issue that there is no string in that dict which has the name `ray` in it, `FindString()` is looking for an exact match in the label. Try it with `Tord Gustavsen Trio`, it should work.

Comment: I assume it's trying to find _Mur_-ray.

Comment: @Someone I stared and stared and just didn't see it. :) Whoops! Still the exact match still stands, I think.

Comment: Yeah, it does look for an exact match. Maybe there's some other string method that works?

Comment: By the way, if you found a solution, could you post it as a self-answer?

Comment: @Someone Apologies for my ingorance of site behavioural norms

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thank you.  I had missed that the searched-for string had to match the whole label.

Answer (score 0):

As the `FindString` function is looking for a match on the label, you will need to manually find partial matches.

One way to achieve that is to use the `wx.ListBox` GetStrings() function and then query that.

Something like this:
(here I query the labels for "`ra`" and then set each item found as Selected)

```
import wx

class TestListBox(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        art = {'A1':'Horace Silver', 'A2':'Murray Perahia', 'A3':'Kieth Jarret',
           'A4':'Andras Schiff', 'A5':'Tord Gustavsen Trio'}
        art = dict(sorted(art.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
        self.lb = wx.ListBox(self, wx.NewIdRef(), choices=[], style=wx.LB_EXTENDED|wx.LB_MULTIPLE)
        self.lb.InsertItems(list(art.values()),0)
        self.lb.Append('Roger the Dodger')
        self.lb.Insert('RolfofSaxony', 1)
        labels = self.lb.GetStrings()
        indicies = self.find_string(labels, 'ra', True)
        print("Matches:", indicies)
        for item in indicies:
            self.lb.SetSelection(item)
        self.Show()

    def find_string(self, search_list, search_str, caseSensitive=False):
        if not caseSensitive:
            lowercase_list = [item.lower() for item in search_list]
            search_list = lowercase_list
            search_str = search_str.lower()
        return [index for (index, item) in enumerate(search_list) if search_str in item]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    TestListBox(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]